# CSS border around div containing span while fitting to content perfectly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a `div` wrapping a `span` element in this way:

```sh
----------
|Sentence|
----------

-----------------
|It's a looooong|
|sentence       |
-----------------
```

It works for short sentences but not for long because the end result is like:

```sh
----------------------
|It's a loooong      |
|sentence            |
----------------------
```

The code is like:

```css
.div-with-border {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.div-with-border span {
    display: block;
}

table{
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width="50%"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="div-with-border">
        <span>Sentence</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div class="div-with-border">
         <span>It's a loooooong sentence</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I basically want to remove the blank gap that exists between the word break and the right limit of the `div` edge, as shown in the example above.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean, do you just need max-width for the div or span?

Comment: I think we need to know more about the container and how its width is defined, and how you want your div's width to be defined in relation.

Comment: If I understand well, in a multi line block, you want the div to be exactly the width of the longest line?

Comment: [like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/ra3ox2hf/) just use a br tag and remove the `max-width`

Comment: @window.document I mean that is nice, but the text should be built dynamically

Comment: What do you mean by _text should be built dynamically?_

Comment: I mean that I just hard coded _This is a long sentence_ for example purposes. The value for the ```span``` is calculated.

Comment: @Renato Damas please check below answer :)

Comment: Or are you looking for something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/esr9zynj/1/)?

Comment: I improved my question. I think it is more clear now

Comment: @RenatoDamas, I think my answer should still work in the context of your updated question. It will fail if you have one word that is longer than your 100px limit. Do you want that to be the only scenario in which the container will grow wider? https://jsfiddle.net/szmcLyx6/

Comment: @MarkLyons you forcing the second ```div``` to have the same width size as the first ```span``` found in the the ```table```. Plus, if there would be a way to avoid javascript, that would be even best.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible in pure CSS. You're right though, I was determining it based on the first `<div>`'s width. Here it is calculating each width individually. https://jsfiddle.net/38uqtram/2/ Note that I removed the `display:block;` declaration for your span.

Comment: is it supposed to used  the longest word  ? if yes then the classic table + width:0 will do the job https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJmeYK

Comment: I had the wrong JSFiddle link originally, here is the correct one with your example: https://jsfiddle.net/9cht0n5g/

Comment: I seem to be close with the property ```display: table-caption;``` on the ```span```. But that breaks short sentences, I don't know why :S

Comment: @RenatoDamas Ah, I gave that a try as well and ran into some difficulties. If it does end up working for you, it would be great if you could post the answer here!

Comment: It does not because that alone breaks A sentence like ```abc def``` in half. Perhaps must be combined with something else

Answer (score 2):

Please make `span` `display:block;` and `text-align:justify`, this will help check below :

```css
.div-with-border {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100px;
}
.div-with-border span{
   text-align: justify;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-with-border">
  <span>This is a long sentence</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The only issue with this is it can result in some crazy bad looking word spacing. Try 'This is sentence' for example.

Comment: It depends on text content if you write "this is a" , it fits perfectly.

Comment: @MarkLyons Exactly, for this example it looks good but not for all cases. For that reason, I can't still accept this answer

Comment: I don't like this answer because the ```text-align: justify;``` property gives it a bad looking result

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of how browsers resize elements when text wraps. I don't think a pure CSS solution to this is possible.

One way you could accomplish this is to calculate the text width in Javascript, as it will not contain this word-wrap edge width. Then you can force the container `<div>`'s width to that:

```
$(".div-with-border").each(function() {
  var textWidth = $(this).find("span").width();
  $(this).width(textWidth);
});
```

I'm using jQuery to do this but you could also use vanilla JS. The width of the text (specifically, the longest line of text) is the `.offsetWidth`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cht0n5g/).